# Display summary of entered field values and permit user to cancel submission

Tags: webforms

Versions: 
   Drupal 7.12
   Webform Module 3.17

I have webform that has multiple pages (using pagebreaks). When the user completes the final page I would like to display a summary of the entered information so that the user can double check it before submitting it.

My first thought (after much searching) was to:

- Use the ***hook_webform_submission_presave*** hook to catch the submission before it is saved
- Display the field values
- If the user decides not to submit the form cancel the submission

However I am having difficulties applying the above theory to reality.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is the above method the best approach (if it is, how do I achieve it)?
3. Or is there a easier/better way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated......Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature request for a "summary" component for Webform in the Webform module issue queue here: http://drupal.org/node/435232, but there isn't any movement yet on actually making a built-in summary component in the core project.

In that issue, dealancer notes that he has already added his code to the http://drupal.org/project/webform_bonus project, which allows you to add a summary component directly to your form in the same way you would add a textfield or any other component type. Install that module and add a summary field to your form, selecting which fields you would like to include in the summary. If you would like it on its own page, make sure to add a pagebreak component first.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for 6.x
The summary component does not show the values but only the field names at the end of the form and just above the 'Submit' button. The 6.x version is broken and unusable